# retrive only where column Element is totally all null

Tags: sql-server

i have two table joined by `ID_Person`

**Table** Person

```
   ID_Person    DateOfEntry Status
    1           2010             Ok 
    2           2009             Ok 
    3          2008          Ok 
    4          2010          Ok
```

**logingTable**

```
ID_Log  YearOfcalculation   Element
1   2008    50
1   2009    60
1   2010    70
1   2011    80
1   2012    90
1   2013    100
1   2014    110
2   1982    NULL
2   1983    50
2   1984    60
2   1985    NULL
2   1986    90
2   1987    100
2   1988    NULL
2   1989    110
3   2000    NULL
3   2001    NULL
3   2002    NULL
3   2003    NULL
3   2004    NULL
3   2005    NULL
3   2006    NULL
4   1978    NULL
4   1979    NULL
4   1980    NULL
4   1981    NULL
4   1982    NULL
4   1983    NULL
4   1984    NULL
```

i want to only to retrieve All ID_Person which element Column is totally null ( i mean there is no any value) 
, in this case only the ID_Person with 3 and 4 must be displayed

```
select ID_Person, Yearofcalculation,Element
from Person
Inner Join LogingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where Element is null
```

but the resultat is not what i expected because it includes the ID_log=2
which some values is not null

Any body can help please 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select ID_Person, Yearofcalculation,Element
from Person
Inner Join LogingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where Element is null
and ID_log not in (select distinct ID_log from LogingTable where Element is not null  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select ID_Person, Yearofcalculation,Element
from Person
Inner Join LogingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where ID_Person NOT IN (
    SELECT a.ID_Log 
    FROM
        logingTable a
    GROUP BY a.ID_Log
    HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(a.Element)
)
```

Only the ID version

```
select DISTINCT ID_Person
from Person
Inner Join LogingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where ID_Person NOT IN (
    SELECT a.ID_Log 
    FROM
        logingTable a
    GROUP BY a.ID_Log
    HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(a.Element)
)
```

Comment: You are comparing Element values to ID_Log - ```...where Element NOT IN (SELECT ID_Log...``` Oopsies :)

Comment: HI , i can not execute the query , it diplays an error ( aggregate function can not be used in the where clause )

Comment: @DVT, I did but that has nothing to do with the error I pointed out in my first comment. Also ```is NOT IN``` is not a valid SQL syntax.

Comment: @Ilyas One more time. I had an extra "is" in there.

Comment: Still issues, where is your group by column? Lol, sorry I'll leave this thread alone now.

Comment: @Anand Bad afternoon, I guess. Copy and paste from two different places.

Comment: i have tried this query but i still got undesired result. i want only to display the ID which all element is null

Answer (score 0):

The clue for this solution is using `ISNULL` function so simply change your `where` criteria to `select` **only the IDs that has NULLs** Only then use the normal select via using the criteria, as next:-

```
select ID_Person,Yearofcalculation,Element
from Person
Inner Join LogingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where ID_Log in (
    select ID_Log  
    from logingTable
    group by ID_Log 
    having isnull(sum (Element),0) = 0
)
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create Table #Person (ID_Person int  , DateOfEntry int , status varchar(3))
go
insert into #Person values (1,2010,'Ok')
insert into #Person values (2,2009,'Ok')
insert into #Person values(3,2008,'Ok')
insert into #Person values(4,2010,'Ok')
go

Create table #logingTable (ID_Log int ,  YearOfcalculation int ,  Element int)
go

insert into #logingTable values (1,2008, 50)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2009, 60)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2010, 70)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2011, 80)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2012, 90)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2013, 100)
insert into #logingTable values (1,2014, 110)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1982, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1983, 50)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1984, 60)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1985, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1986, 90)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1987, 100)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1988, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (2,1989, 110)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2000, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2001, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2002, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2003, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2004, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2005, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (3,2006, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1978, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1979, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1980, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1981, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1982, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1983, NULL)
insert into #logingTable values (4,1984, NULL)

go

select ID_Person,Yearofcalculation,Element
from #Person
Inner Join #logingTable 
ON ID_Person=ID_log
where ID_Log in (
    select ID_Log  
    from #logingTable
    group by ID_Log 
    having isnull(sum (Element),0) = 0
)
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[1] First solution:

```
SELECT ID_Person
FROM Person
INNER JOIN LogingTable ON ID_Person=ID_log
GROUP BY ID_Person
HAVING SUM(Element) is null
```

[2] Second solution:

```
SELECT ... list of columns ...
FROM LogingTable 
WHERE ID_log IN (
    SELECT ID_Person
    FROM Person
    INNER JOIN LogingTable ON ID_Person=ID_log
    GROUP BY ID_Person
    HAVING SUM(Element) is null
)

[3] Third solution:

SELECT ... list of columns ...
FROM (
    SELECT lt.*, SUM(lt.Element) OVER(PARTITION BY lt.ID_Log) AS SumOfElement
    FROM LogingTable lt
) x
WHERE x.SumOfElement = 0
```